# how find a maximal set or a superset from a list of sets (Maximal set is the set which is not subset of another set in the list)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, set

This is about finding dense communities in a graph based on density criteria and all the sets below are dense communities of a graph

```
list L=[set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([4]), set([5]), set([6]), set([7]), set([8]), set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 4]), set([3, 4]), set([1, 3, 4]), set([1, 5]), set([2, 5]), set([4, 5]), set([1, 2, 5]), set([1, 4, 5]), set([2, 6]), set([4, 7]), set([8, 5]), set([8, 7])]
```

I need to get the maximal sets of this list i,e. in the list set([1,4,5]) is the maximal set of sets([1]),set([4]),set([5]),set([1,5]),set([1,4]) and set([4,5]) so I need to onlye print out set([1,4,5]) similarly set([1]),set([3]).set([4]),set([1,3]),set([1,4]),set([3,4]) has a maximal set  set([1,3,4]) so I need to print out only set([1,3,4]) as you can see set([1,2,5]) is  a maximal set and all the sets which are not a subset of larger sets are considered as maximal sets so I need to get only the maximal sets which are not subset of a larger set

Comment: Didn't you ask this question before?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.

Answer (score 2):

```
L=[set([1]), set([2]), set([3]), set([4]), set([5]), set([6]), set([7]), set([8]), set([1, 2]), set([1, 3]), set([1, 4]), set([3, 4]), set([1, 3, 4]), set([1, 5]), set([2, 5]), set([4, 5]), set([1, 2, 5]), set([1, 4, 5]), set([2, 6]), set([4, 7]), set([8, 5]), set([8, 7])]


#this grouping the list by there length ...
values = set(map(lambda x:len(x), L))
newlist = {x:[y for y in L if len(y)==x] for x in values}
maxlen=max(values)

#checking for the subset.if no subset.it is returned

for i in values:
    print [ key for key in newlist[i] if not any([ val.intersection(key)==key for j in values if j !=i for val in newlist[j] ])]


#output =[set([2, 6]), set([4, 7]), set([8, 5]), set([8, 7])] [set([1, 3, 4]), set([1, 2, 5]), set([1, 4, 5])]
```

Comment: @user2014111 pleasure is mine

Comment: Ia m unable to accept..

Comment: @user2014111 its fine. just asking